# Using JQuery to change text color on value input if validation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply want my text in the value input box to change to red if my php validation fails?

how can this be done using JQuery?

I did it using Javascript except every time i click submit it turns red and then disappears...

```
    <form class="link-form" method="post" action="">
    <label>DIRECT LINK</label>
    <input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['url'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['url']); } ?>" />
    <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Generate Direct Link" />   
    <?php
        $directLink = "";
        $error = "";
        $url = $_POST['url'];
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $partsUrl = parse_url($url);

            if ($partsUrl["scheme"] === "https://" && $partsUrl["host"] === "example.com/") 
            {
                $key = substr($partsUrl["path"],8,-5);
                $directLink = "https://example.com/".htmlspecialchars($key);    
            }
            else
            {
                $error = "Invalid, Please insert the correct Link";
            }
        }
    ?>
    <label>DIRECT LINK</label>
    <input type="text" id="directLink" name="directLink" value="<?php if (!empty($directLink)) { echo $directLink; } else { echo $error; } ?>" />
</form>

function colorChange() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("directLink").value;
    if (inputVal === "Invalid, Please insert the correct Link") {
        document.getElementById("directLink").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("directLink").style.backgroundColor = "black";      
    }
}
```

Or I tried the JQuery example below but did nothing.

```
$('#submit').on('click',function(){

  var text = $('#directLink').val();
  if(text === 'Invalid, Please insert the correct Link'){
    $('#directLink').css({'background-color':'red !important'});
  }

});
```

Comment: You should provide relevant parts of your script and HTML

Comment: thats the javascript I used that works but only temporarily, after i click it turns red then returns to default value.

Comment: First off, if you'd want the text color to change, then it's `style.color = "red";`

Comment: oh yeah i know, either way it produces the same effect.

Comment: Please provide whole code. Do you use ajax for data sending?

Comment: There you go, no I am not using ajax, I have never really used Ajax before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `css` method to set `background-color` on your text field like this

```
$('#directLink').css({'backgroundColor':'red'});
```

If you just want to change your text color to red, you should set `color` property

```
$('#directLink').css({'color':'red'});
```

If you try to use `red !important`, it will simply FAIL without any error because jQuery has a problem understanding `!important`. If you really need to use that, have a look at these workarounds but in your case I think !important is really not needed :)

Few more changes :-

1. Return false in your if condition to prevent the form from
   submitting in case of error scenarios
2. Check for the value of url instead of directLink as it won't work
   next time you post a valid url, directLink is still with error
   message and the form won't get submitted.

Here's a [bin](http://jsbin.com/wecoxibosa/1/edit?html,js,output) to play with.

Comment: Hmmm, it works in the bin, but when im doing it in my own form it does not change if text === 'Invalid, Please insert the correct Link'. How do i  get the javascript to check if text is equivalent after submit, so after it is in the input box.

Comment: Do you see any errors in console ? It would be better if you can add your textbox html and jquery code you tried. Pls edit and add it to your question

Comment: color in css means font color, as your text box is empty, it will change the cursor in your text box to red, you have to pay attention to notice that. If you really want to give some visual feedback to user, you should change `background-color` not `color`

Comment: Also you're the checking the value of `url` but changing `directLink`.. is that your intent ? check value of an input box in form and highlight some other box ?

Comment: Any specific reason for using `!important`. You're not supposed to use that unless you inherit some styles for which you don't have to access to :)

Comment: Sorry just edited the code to what I am using now, still no success, ignore the !important, i was just experimenting :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73516/discussion-between-arkantos-and-c-had1990).